# What's the intended purpose of the Book of Regression?

Tags: path-of-exile

[image]

The Book of Regression, an item you get by vendoring an Orb of Scouring with 1x Scroll of Wisdom, apparently downlevels your character by 1 and resets all exp to 0.

What I want to understand is, for what reason would this be used for?  The only obvious answer that comes to my mind is that certain PvP characters would want to be at a specific level threshold, and this would allow them to get to that threshold, but other than that I can't think of any realistic use for this.

Is there some intended use for this item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of release 3.21.0 this item [will be removed](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/3361403#itembalance). This will launch on 7/4/2023 (7th April 2023).

> You can no longer create Books of Regression. Existing unused Books of Regression will be destroyed when 3.21 is deployed.

Apparently this was a solution to prevent "infinite heist" strategy. Vendor shops refresh when you level up so this involved using the item to refresh vendor shops and buy new heist contracts.

[Additionally covered in questions](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/3324396):

> **Was the removal of Books of Regression intended to nerf the strategy that involved using them for Heist?**
>
> Books of Regression were removed because their intended purpose (related to PvP characters) is no longer relevant. The way they were being used in Heist was not intended.

Answer (score 4):

### 1. Self-imposed challenge.

Do you want to kill Uber-elder on lvl 1 character? With some Books of Regression you can try.

### 2. Farm in low-level locations.

Some divination cards can drop in low level locations, but [Drop Rate penalty](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Drop_rate#Drop_Penalty) may prevent effective farm. Books of Regression allow to keep character on specific level to avoid this penalty.

### 3. Leaderboards

Some players want to compete for a place on [Labyrinth Leaderboards](https://www.pathofexile.com/ladder/labyrinth/Standard/1/1568592000), some of them have level limits - 40 for Normal and 60 for Cruel.

Comment: How would you farm for Oni-Goroshi with this though? That seems impossible, considering Uber Hillock is locked into Twilight Strand, and you can't access the Twilight Strand at all, if only at the start of the game.

Comment: @senpai you are correct, it's not possible to fight Hillock again after entering town

Comment: The book of regression was added in the patch directly following the lab leader boards. I would say that is the number 1 intended function for the book as you need to be under a certain level to be eligible for rewards.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent suggestions by @arghtype @VanBuzzKill (lab is the reason for the season on the book) there is a very similar potential XP penalty for a given area relative to your character level.

See [Experience penalties](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Experience#Experience_penalties) in PoE wiki.

If your level is too low or high for an area you do not gain the same rate of XP. This changes a bit at level 95 where the grind gets grind-y-er.

**who would be interested?**

- Racers optimizing their progression to be very min-maxed (they try to barely skate through some of those Act1-4 zones where the leveling gear is throwaway SSF anyway)
- if you find yourself hitting a wall and progression is stale something needs a second look this could be a small part